# Exclude objects whose date time field values are greater than the current date and time

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a class To Do and it has a dead line property.

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    dead_line = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to get all the to-do's except for the to-do's whose dead line value has crossed current date and time. I tried this way:

```
to_do_list = user.todo_set.all().exclude(dead_line__lte=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')))
```

But, this gives me all the to-dos.

Again, this works just fine and excludes the to-do's which are of current day:

```
to_do_list = user.todo_set.all().exclude(dead_line__day=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).day)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get all the to-do's whose dead line is greater that current date and time?

**Update**

I have setup `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` and `USE_TZ = True`

Sample data:

```
>>> datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
'2018-03-14 05:04 PM'

>>> user.todo_set.all()
<QuerySet [<ToDo: Run on 2018-03-18 08:30 AM>, <ToDo: Learn on 2018-03-14 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Ready on 2018-03-15 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Play on 2018-03-16 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Hunt on 2018-03-17 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Test on 2018-03-18 11:30 AM>]>
```

As you can see, the ToDo object `<ToDo: Learn on 2018-03-14 11:30 AM>` should be excluded from the list when excluding the list, but it doesn't.

**Update**

By looping using the for loop, returns the expected results.

```
>>> to_do_list = []
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for todo in user.todo_set.all():
...     if todo.dead_line > datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')):
...             to_do_list.append(todo)
...
>>> to_do_list
[<ToDo: Run on 2018-03-18 08:30 AM>, <ToDo: Ready on 2018-03-15 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Play on 2018-03-16 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Hunt on 2018-03-17 11:30 AM>, <ToDo: Test on 2018-03-18 11:30 AM>]
```

Comment: `__gte=` current date?

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri That returns me empy list `<QuerySet []>`

Comment: oh yeah use `.set.filter(..._gte=` instead of exclude

Comment: Totally unrelated, but `object.all()` is only useful if and when you have no `filter`, `exclude`, `values()` etc calls - IOW you want `user.todo_set.exclude(...)`. This won't sole your problem in any way but at least it will make your code more readable and avoid cloning a queryset for nothing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yep! Sorry, my bad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get all the to-do's whose dead line is greater that current date and time

I guess you are using `lte` instead of `gt` (greater than)? get only todos whose deadline is later than now

> to_do_list = user.todo_set.all().filter(dead_line__gt=datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')))

Unless you stored everything with timezone Koalkata, this can be an empty queryset. you should always use UTC.
Notice that you are looking up the ToDos of certain user. Make sure the user has data.

the second approach you use seems wrong. you're comparing the day, which is a number in the range 1-30, aprox https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html:

> date.day
>     Between 1 and the number of days in the given month of the given year

Comment: Using `gt` returns an empy list `<QuerySet []>`. And I have setup `TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'` in my django settings.

Comment: maybe you can add sample data to the post. `ToDo.objects.all()` if there aren't many

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter()`

```
from django.utils import timezone
user.todo_set.filter(dead_line_date__gt=timezone.now())
```

And update your settings to use timezone aware

```
USE_TZ=True
```

Comment: `queryset.filter(dead_line__gt=somedatetime)` and `queryset.exclude(dead_line__lte=somedatime)` are equivalent.